# Is there any modal verb to show possibility in present?

Tags: grammar

In my language there is a modal verb which can be used for present possibility but in English as far as I know we have to rely on words like possibly,perhaps,maybe etc

We use the modals could, might and may to show that something is possible in the future, but not certain

And could have,might have for past possibility

But what about present possibility?

Comment: As you wrote "I know we have to rely on words like possibly,perhaps,maybe etc", could you add some examples using those words? That would make it easier to understand your intent.

Comment: You can check comments on rjpond's answer

Answer (score 1):

The word "can" is used for present possibility.

> Can you jump as high as this?
>
> Can you do my homework for me?
>
> I can cook dinner, if you like.
>
> Can you stay a while?
>
> I can't sleep.
>
> I can either study or watch television.  I'm trying to decide.
>
> Can you sign this for me?

Of course, there are cases where "can" would be unidiomatic and we use "may" ("I won't call him now - he may be asleep") or an adverb such as "perhaps".

Although "might" is technically a past tense modal, it can also be used to describe present possibility (as well as future, as you noted):

> She might love me, but I don't know for sure.
>
> He might be out shopping.
>
> She might be at her desk.  I'll check.
>
> It might be raining.  I'll look outside and see.
>
> Isn't it working?  It might need re-charging, or it might be broken.

Comment: Lol no. I'm talking about present simple. For example Perhaps she loves me.  It does not mean She can love me. xD xD

Comment: You can say "she might love me".

Comment: But that would become a future tense. Wont it?

Comment: No, "might" can describe the future ("I might go shopping tomorrow") or the present ("he might be home already", "it's late - she might be asleep", "he might know the answer").

Comment: +1. Like **might**, **could** can also describe a present possibility. It depends on the accompanying verb.  *He could **be** home by now, or he could **have run** into traffic.*

Comment: What does this sentence mean? Who might love me?

Comment: It's hard to determine the exact meaning out of context.  I suspect it is asking about the present.  However, a more idiomatic way of expressing the thought might be "I wonder who loves me" (as a thought to oneself) or (as a question to someone) "Who do you think loves me?" or "Who do you think might love me?".

Comment: @rjpond By who might love me i want to say who possibly(perhaps) loves me

Comment: You there? 

Comment: Well, if you wanted someone to speculate on who loves you, you'd be more likely to say "who do you think loves me?" or "who do you think might love me?".  But if you want to express your exact question then, yes, "who might love me?" could work.  You certainly wouldn't say "who could/would/can love me?", which would probably all be interpreted as rhetorical questions suggesting an answer of "no one".  And "who might love me?" is actually more idiomatic English than "who possibly/perhaps loves me?".

Comment: Btw why can't I use would here in place of might?

Comment: "Who would love me?" is grammatically correct but it has a different meaning.  It's talking about a hypothetical: who would love me if/when/after I did X, or X happened, etc.  My point was that out of context "who would love me?" might be taken to be a rhetorical question, "who would (ever) love me?", asked in despair.  But there could be other situations where it might have a different meaning.  However, this meaning wouldn't be the same as that expressed by "might". "Who might love me?" might be asking about present possibility, "who would" is a conditional.

Comment: Okay i get it. But who might love me sounds like a one time action to me whereas who possibly/perhaps loves me sounds habitual and an unchanging situation

Comment: You there @rjpond?

Comment: I don't think I'd agree with the distinction you're drawing there.